# Reindex method of Pandas does not respect the set frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency, datetimeindex

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a daily DatetimeIndex. I am trying to apply the Resample method to sum the values into a monthly series like this:

```
>>> aggVols.resample('M',axis=1).sum()
```

But when I try this I get the error

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

I noticed that the frequency of the index of the object is not set (None).

```
>>>aggVols.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2016-01-04, ..., 2016-07-01]
Length: 130, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

So I first set the frequency to daily (business day) and reset the index so that I can apply resample:

```
>>> aggVols    = aggVols.reindex(aggVols.asfreq('B').index)
>>> aggVols.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2016-01-04, ..., 2016-07-01]
Length: 130, Freq: B, Timezone: None
```

But I am still getting the same error our of the resample function:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

What is wrong with the index? Why is it not valid?
I get the same error if I set the frequency to D.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a sample of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it in the end. Was using the method the wrong way with the operation at the end, as if it was a series. The right code is:

```
aggVols.resample('M',axis=0,how=sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
aggVols.resample('M',axis=1).sum()
```

to

```
aggVols.resample('M',axis=0).sum()
```

Your `DatetimeIndex` is on the rows (not the columns).

In general axis 0 is the rows, axis 1 is the columns, axis 2 is the height, and axes 3-N ... well they are thought about more abstractly.

See the "along an axis" section of [the NumPy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/glossary.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, DatetimeIndex is for the rows (not the columns). So I might be indeed specifying the wrong axis. But what you suggest give me a single number per colum. It is not producing a monthly series.
'>>> aggVols.resample('M',axis=0).sum()
    CMX      114237.608293
    LME     1425516.887879
    SHF    50861180.513820
    dtype: float64'

Comment: @David you want to sum across the rows of the DataFrame?

Comment: @David it helps if you post a sample DataFrame and your desired result.

Comment: Answered my own question above. Thanks anyway for the help.